# $O$ is a point inside cube such that $\vec{OA}+\vec{OB}+\vec{OC}+\vec{OD}=\vec{OM_1}$

Tags: vectors, 3d

Given a cube $ABCDA_1B_1C_1D_1$ with lower base $ABCD$ and upper base $A_1B_1C_1D_1$ and the lateral edges $AA_1,BB_1,CC_1,DD_1$ respectively. $M$ and $M_1$ are centres of the faces $ABCD$ and $A_1B_1C_1D_1$ respectively. $O$ is a point on line $MM_1$, such that $\vec{OA}+\vec{OB}+\vec{OC}+\vec{OD}=\vec{OM_1}$. If $\vec{OM}=\lambda \vec{OM_1}$. Then find the value of $\lambda$.

Could someone give me some hint about this question. I am not able to visualize it.

Comment: What is $mm_1$.

Comment: @ArchisWelankar Thanx for pointing that out. It has been edited.

Comment: is $\lambda=1$ the answer

Comment: @ArchisWelankar No. $\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{8},\frac{1}{16}$ are the options.

Comment: There's probably some notational mistake in the question, since if you sketch the cube and vectors, it doesn't really make sense to say that the vectors $OA$, $OB$, $OC$, $OD$ add to $OM_1$, since the first four vectors point downwards, but $OM_1$ points upwards. Probably, the $OM_1$'s should be $M_1O$'s, and the equation $OM=λOM1$ should be $OM=λM_1O$. Algebraically, you get the same answer either way (the geometry just makes more sense this way).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing you should do is sketch the cube and all the vectors involved.

From your picture, you should be able to see that $\vec{OA}=\vec{OM}+\vec{MA}$. Similarly, $\vec{OB}=\vec{OM}+\vec{MB},$ and the same for $\vec{OC}$ and $\vec{OD}$.

Then, plugging that into the equation given, we have: 
$$\vec{OA}+\vec{OB}+\vec{OC}+\vec{OD}=\vec{OM_1}$$
$$(\vec{OM}+\vec{MA})+(\vec{OM}+\vec{MB})+(\vec{OM}+\vec{MC})+(\vec{OM}+\vec{MD})=\vec{OM_1}$$
$$4\vec{OM}+\vec{MA}+\vec{MB}+\vec{MC}+\vec{MD}=\vec{OM_1}$$

Now, again looking at your picture, you should be able to see that $\vec{MA}$ and $\vec{MC}$ are opposite vectors - that is, they are parallel and of the same length, but pointing in the opposite direction (since $M$ is the centre of the bottom face). So, we can write $\vec{MA}=-\vec{MC}$. Similarly, $\vec{MB}=-\vec{MD}.$ Because of this, we get $\vec{MA}+\vec{MB}+\vec{MC}+\vec{MD}=\vec{0}$.

This gives us: 
$$4\vec{OM}=\vec{OM_1}.$$
Plugging in $\vec{OM}=\lambda\vec{OM_1}$, you can now solve for $\lambda$!